# Why is it possible that the White test and the special case of the White test can give different values of $R^2$

Tags: econometrics, heteroscedasticity, r-squared

In the textbook I am using ([*Introductory Econometrics: A Modern Approach*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1111531048) by Jeffrey M. Wooldridge, 5e), it is implied that the $R^2$ from the regression of residual-squared on all independent variables in the original model, their squares, and interactions will always be at least as large as the $R^2$ from the special case of the White test. (This topic is from chapter 8.)

However, the textbook does not explain why it is so. Could anybody explain this instead? If anyone could playfully try explaining this within 140 words, I would appreciate that too.

If you have the textbook, you can refer to the page 298, (ii) of 6.

Comment: @user777 Of course. Any answer is appreciated as long as it's fair.

Answer (score 1):

The special case for White test frees you of constructing plenty of items, which also saves a lot of degrees of freedom. However, fitted value of the dependent variable will impose constraint on all the regressors, since hat y is a regressed result and a linear combination of all explanatory variables.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).